# Cannot use request and yield in quart handler

Tags: python, quart

I am trying to use async generator and quart to stream the result of bigger queries. However I am stuck in yielding from an async function while using the `request` argument of the HTTP query

```
from quart import request, Quart
app = Quart(__name__)

@app.route('/')
async def function():
    arg = request.args.get('arg')
    yield 'HelloWorld'
```

Start with `hypercorn module:app` and calling it with `curl localhost:8000/?arg=monkey` results in

```
[...]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/andre/src/cid-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/quart/utils.py", line 88, in _inner
    return next(iterable)
  File "/home/andre/src/cid/mve.py", line 7, in function
    arg = request.args.get('arg')
  File "/home/andre/src/cid-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 422, in __get__
    obj = instance._get_current_object()
  File "/home/andre/src/cid-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 544, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()  # type: ignore
  File "/home/andre/src/cid-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/quart/globals.py", line 26, in _ctx_lookup
    raise RuntimeError(f"Attempt to access {name} outside of a relevant context")
RuntimeError: Attempt to access request outside of a relevant context
```

Comment: Changing the `yield` to a `return` works perfectly ... but not what I intended

Comment: Your function isn't an async generator — does it work if you change it from `def function():` to `async def function():`?

Comment: @L3viathan I made a mistake in my example, sry. I talked to the maintainer over on https://gitter.im/python-quart/lobby. From his perspective it looks like a bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the stream_with_context decorator and return a generator to achieve this, see these [docs](https://pgjones.gitlab.io/quart/how_to_guides/streaming_response.html#with-context),

```py
from quart import request, stream_with_context, Quart

app = Quart(__name__)

@app.route('/')
async def function():
    @stream_with_context
    async def _gen():
        arg = request.args.get('arg')
        yield 'HelloWorld'
    return _gen()
```

Comment: and there is the answer from the project owner :)